# Selecting from multiple tables linq Web API

Tags: linq

I have problem selecting data from two tables. Here is my code

```
var results = (from voter in context.Voters
                          join voter2 in context.PollingShehias on voter.PollingStationId equals voter2.PollingStationId
                          join poll in context.PollingStations on voter.PollingStationId equals poll.Id
                          where voter2.WordId == Id
                          orderby voter.FirstName, voter.MiddleName, voter.LastName, voter.Gender ascending
                          select new 
                          {
                              voter.Id,
                              voter.FirstName,
                              voter.MiddleName,
                              voter.LastName,
                              voter.DateBirth,
                              voter.Gender,
                              voter.ResidentialAddress,
                              poll.Name,
                              voter.VoterIDNumber,
                              voter.LifeStatus
                          });

return results;
```

When I select new I get the following error

> ExceptionMessage":"Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'Cuf.infrastructure.Models.Voter'.

Comment: Well, you're selecting an anonymous type.  Presumably the method is expecting to return the `Voter` type?  You can select that type, or create a new instance of that type from the results?  What are you trying to do?  What should the method return?

Comment: method return IEnumerable<Models.Voter> GetVoteer(int id)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`select new { ... }`

with

`select voter`

But in this case you won't be able to return `poll.Name`. Probably you need to create a new class with `PollName` property and return its `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<Voter>`.

E.g.:

```
public class VoterWithPollName {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public sitrng FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateBirth { get; set; }
    public sting Gender { get; set; }
    public string ResidentialAddress { get; set; }
    public string PollName { get; set; }
    public long VoterIDNumber { get; set; }
    public string LifeStatus { get; set; }
}

...

// set method return type to IEnumerable<VoterWithPollName>

var results = (from voter in context.Voters
                          join voter2 in context.PollingShehias on voter.PollingStationId equals voter2.PollingStationId
                          join poll in context.PollingStations on voter.PollingStationId equals poll.Id
                          where voter2.WordId == Id
                          orderby voter.FirstName, voter.MiddleName, voter.LastName, voter.Gender ascending
                          select new VoterWithPollName
                          {
                              Id = voter.Id,
                              FirstName = voter.FirstName,
                              MiddleName = voter.MiddleName,
                              LastName = voter.LastName,
                              DateBirth = voter.DateBirth,
                              Gender = voter.Gender,
                              ResidentialAddress = voter.ResidentialAddress,
                              PollName = poll.Name,
                              VoterIDNumber = voter.VoterIDNumber,
                              LifeStatus = voter.LifeStatus
                          });

return results;
```

Comment: poll.Name is where I get problem

Comment: Added an example

Comment: BTW, `VoterIDNumber` should be `VoterIdNumber` according to guidelines

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Voter is class ( model) name

So you write code

```
 voter in context.Voters
```

voter is Model Or Class name but this time is an object

but class name and object name same then Anonymous type exception

So You have voter  change  Vote or any name

How to avoid to plural table name problem

Following Write Code

In your myDB context class, override the following method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help